# What is the necessary condition on EM field for vanishing Poynting vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, poynting-vector

It is well known fact that both static and dynamic EM fields can give $E\times B \not=0$. What can we say about EM field if $E\times B =0$ ? Can previous equation still hold in case of dynamic EM field ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: The cross product is zero if the vectors it is taken with are parallel. Now, think, how could that happen for an EM field?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I understand what you are saying. Perhaps, EM field propagate only if E and B are perpendicular (not parallel) so there is no dynamical case. The thing is that I am looking for the precise "proof". If equation $E\times B=0$ hold what can be said about EM? Is there any non-trivial solution at all?